# Google Maps API V3 - How to fired function with button outside the map (without to reload the map)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I find this example for draggable markers http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/draggable-markers/draggable-markers.html that's pretty cool, but I would like to first upload map with my markers (that are stored insdie MySQL) and have optional button on the page outside the map that will allow the user to fire this functionality if he want (without to reload the map).

Code from http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/draggable-markers/draggable-markers.html are displayed below:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function geocodePosition(pos) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    latLng: pos
  }, function(responses) {
    if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
      updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
    } else {
      updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
    }
  });
}

function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
  document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;
}

function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
    latLng.lat(),
    latLng.lng()
  ].join(', ');
}

function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
  document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
}

function initialize() {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    title: 'Point A',
    map: map,
    draggable: true
  });

  // Update current position info.
  updateMarkerPosition(latLng);
  geocodePosition(latLng);

  // Add dragging event listeners.
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
    updateMarkerAddress('Dragging...');
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
    updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');
    updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
    geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
  });
}

// Onload handler to fire off the app.
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <style>
  #mapCanvas {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
  }
  #infoPanel {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  #infoPanel div {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  </style>

  <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
  <div id="infoPanel">
    <b>Marker status:</b>
    <div id="markerStatus"><i>Click and drag the marker.</i></div>
    <b>Current position:</b>
    <div id="info"></div>
    <b>Closest matching address:</b>
    <div id="address"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Best,
Darko

Comment: So? What's the problem?

Comment: So, how to fired function with button outside the map (without to reload the map)?

Comment: What function? Are you looking for [a clickable sidebar](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map2.html)?  Or do you want to reverse geocode your points on the click?

Comment: I have already markers from MySQL and I want to display marker (draggable marker) on the click from the sidebar without to reload the map, so the markers from MySQL stay on the map, and draggable marker only be added to existing markers (from MySQL) that are already on the map.